# Bash Regex Pattern Matching: How To Use Variables Inside of Pattern Variable?

Tags: regex, bash, regex-group

I'm trying to **a)** scan a string for a pattern match **b)** save the matches to a list **c)** filter the matches from the original string.

No matter the regex I use, it just won't match. I think the problem is the way I'm using a variable in the regex pattern variable, and/or the way I'm defining [space].

### **Suspected problem code:**

```
trig_chars='\s\s' # Double space # Can be numbers, spaces, a-z, A-Z, or special chars.
        
pat_before_after="^[^\s]$trig_chars[^\s]" # Any characters before or after trig chars until space or beginning/end of query hit.
    
if [[ "$accum" =~ "$pat_before_after" ]] ; then  # Trig char found.
```

Am I defining $trig_chars right in the  $pat_before_after var?  Am I using the vars correctly in the regex compare statement?

### **More context:**

This is what I'm trying to do:

**Example:**

> raw_query='A[space][space] this is a Bcd[space][space] test
> e$F[space][space] query [space][space] G'
>
> hotstrings=('A' 'Bcd' 'e$F' 'G')
>
> filtered_query='this is a test query'

From $raw_query get $hotstrings and $filtered_query.

### Here's how I'm trying to do it:

Recursive search through each string character until a match is found.  Remove the match.  And build the filtered query var from the unmatched characters.

(I suspect this is not the way to do it, but haven't been successful getting tests to pass with other attempts.)

### Here's the related code in full context:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Gets hotstrings from raw query.
# Returns hotstrings and filtered query, with trigger characters and hotstrings removed.

#Global vars
raw_query='' # User input thru Zenity
# trig_chars='  ' # Double space
trig_chars='\s\s' # Double space 
hotstrings=() # Any chars in raw_query before/after trig chars until space or beginning/end of query hit.
filtered_query='' # Raw_query with hotstrings & trig chars removed.

pat_before_after="^[^\s]$trig_chars[^\s]" # Any characters before or after trig chars until space or beginning/end of query hit.

# Scans raw query for trig chars & hotstrings.
# Filters trig chars & hotstrings from filtered_query var.
get_hotstrings(){
    # Guard clause edge case, no trigger chars defined.
    if [ "$trig_chars" == "" ]; then 
        filtered_query="$raw_query"
    return; fi

    local scan_text="$raw_query"
    local accum='' # Used to accumulate unmatched chars.
    filtered_query='' # Blank out filtered query before scan.

    while [ "$scan_text" != "" ]; do # Recursive search thru each char.
        local next_char=${scan_text:0:1}
        local accum="$accum$next_char" 

        if [[ "$accum" =~ "$pat_before_after" ]] ; then  # Trig char found.  

            local l=${#accum}
            local scan_text=${scan_text:$l} # Remove chars & hotscan_texts from scan_text.

            hotstring=${BASH_REMATCH[1]} # Get hotstring from pattern match.
             
            hotstrings+=("$hotstring") # Update hotstrings list
            local accum='' # Start new accumulator.
        else
            filtered_query="$filtered_query$next_char" # Build the filtered query from non-matched chars.
            scan_text=${scan_text:1} # remove char.
        fi
    done
    
}


################### TESTS ##################

test_messages(){
    #$1=test_name
    #$2=expected result.
    #$3=actual result.

    msg="Test name:$1
    Expected result:$2
    Actual result:$3"

    if [ "$2" == "$3" ]; then
        msg2='SUCCESS'
    else
        msg2='FAILED'
    fi
    echo "$msg"
    echo "$msg2"
}

hotstring_scan_test(){
    #$1=Test name
    #$2=raw query
    #$3=trig chars
    #$4=Expected hotstrings.
    #$5=Expected filtered query.

    raw_query="$2"
    trig_chars="$3"
    
    get_hotstrings
    r="${hotstrings[*]}"
    
    msg1="Test name: $1 
    Raw query: $2 
    Trig chars: $3" 

    if [ "$r" == "$4" ]; then
        msg2="SUCCESS"
    else
        msg2="Expected hotstring result:$4 
        Actual hotstring result:$r
        FAILED"
    fi
    echo "$msg1"
    echo "$msg2"
    echo ""

    msg1="Filtered query test:
    Filtered query: $filtered_query"

    if [ "$filtered_query" == "$5" ]; then
        msg2="SUCCESS"
    else
        msg2="Expected result:$5 
        Actual result:$filtered_query 
        FAILED"
    fi
    echo "$msg1"
    echo "$msg2" 
    echo ""
}
    
hotstring_scan_tests(){
    local t_name='No trigger chars defined'
    local q='Test query without hotstrings or trigger chars'
    raw_query="$q"
    local eq='Test query without hotstrings or trigger chars'
    local tc=''
    local eh=''
    hotstring_scan_test "$t_name" "$q" "$tc" "$eh" "$eq"
    filtered_query=''

    local t_name='No trigger chars defined'
    local q='Test query without hotstrings or trigger chars'
    raw_query="$q"
    local eq='Test query without hotstrings or trigger chars'
    local tc='**'
    local eh=''
    hotstring_scan_test "$t_name" "$q" "$tc" "$eh" "$eq"
    filtered_query=''

    local t_name='Double space trigger chars'
    local q='  aabc Test   b Query with Hotstrings removed   c'
    raw_query="$q"
    local eq='Test Query with Hotstrings removed'
    local tc='  '
    local eh='aabc b c'
    hotstring_scan_test "$t_name" "$q" "$tc" "$eh" "$eq"
    filtered_query=''

    local t_name='Double space after trigger chars'
    local q='aabc   Test b   Query with Hotstrings removed c  '
    raw_query="$q"
    local eq='Test Query with Hotstrings removed'
    local tc='  '
    local eh='aabc b c'
    hotstring_scan_test "$t_name" "$q" "$tc" "$eh" "$eq"
    filtered_query=''


    local t_name='Trigger chars before hotstring'
    local q='**aabc Test **b Query with Hotstrings removed **c'
    raw_query="$q"
    local eq='Test Query with Hotstrings removed'
    local tc='**'
    local eh='aabc b c'
    hotstring_scan_test "$t_name" "$q" "$tc" "$eh" "$eq"
    filtered_query=''

    local t_name='Trigger chars after hotstring'
    local q='aabc** Test b** Query with Hotstrings removed c**'
    raw_query="$q"
    local eq='Test Query with Hotstrings removed'
    local tc='**'
    local eh='aabc b c'
    hotstring_scan_test "$t_name" "$q" "$tc" "$eh" "$eq"
    filtered_query=''

    local t_name='Trigger chars before & after hotstring'
    local q='aabc** Test **B$! Query with Hotstrings removed **c123'
    raw_query="$q"
    local eq='Test Query with Hotstrings removed'
    local tc='**'
    local eh='aabc B$1! c123'
    hotstring_scan_test "$t_name" "$q" "$tc" "$eh" "$eq"
    filtered_query=''


}

performance_test(){
    start=$(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))

    for i in {1..10000}; do
        run_all_tests
    done

    end=$(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))
    execution_time=$(expr $end - $start)

    echo "Execution time in nano seconds: $execution_time"
}

run_all_tests(){
    set -x
    hotstring_scan_tests

}

run_all_tests
# performance_test
```

Comment: Does this help (from bash manual): _If the pattern is stored in a shell variable, quoting the variable expansion forces the entire  pattern  to be matched as a string_?

Answer (score 3):

According to `man bash` the use of `"` (double quote) with `"$pat_before_after"` will force the match of the entire string with the pattern in the variable.

In the same `man bash`, the pattern is a regular expression as defined in `man 7 regex`: I mean `\s` is not a placeholder for space, try `[[:blank:]]` or `[[:space:]]` instead  (**EDIT** see comments).

a test (**EDIT** see comments):

```
trig_chars='[[:space:]][[:space:]]'
pat_before_after="^[^[:space:]]${trig_chars}[^[:space:]]"
accum='f  daaa'
if [[ $accum =~ $pat_before_after ]] ; then
  printf 'Match!\n'
fi
```

result:

```
Match!
```

Comment: Nice. If the `\s` in the OP was a replacement for `[[:space:]]`, as is frequently seen, replace `blank` by `space`. Note: the double quotes and curly braces are not needed in `[[ ... ]]`.

Comment: Super ! thank you! I do not find this information, what should I read?

Comment: The bash manual is the ultimate reference. Example of what you can find there: _The parameter name or symbol to be  expanded may  be enclosed in braces, which are optional but serve to protect the variable to be expanded from characters immediately following it which could be interpreted as part of the name_ That's for the useless curly braces. Also: _Word splitting and pathname expansion are not performed on the words between the [[  and  ]]_ That's for double quotes around `$accum`: no word splitting, no need for them.

Comment: But I would say that you don't really learn all this by reading the bash manual from beginning to end while drinking your morning coffee. One day you see a surprising construct that you didn't know or that you intuitively consider as weird, you dig a bit in the manual and discover a new aspect. Same for most utilities (`awk`, `sed`, `grep`, `find`...)

Comment: @RenaudPacalet : Agreed ! thx ! I am writing bash scripts and using those (great) listed commands; but never noticed these details about the use of ```[[ ... ]]```. Once I started to use the curly braces, I think I used them everywhere (also it helps reading) ?

Comment: Using `${var}` instead of just `$var`, and double-quoting variables inside `[[ ]]` aren't bad, just unnecessary (except double-quoting patterns on the right of a `=~` or `=` comparison). I tend to double-quote even when it's not necessary, because remembering exactly when it's safe to omit the double-quotes is more trouble than just always using them.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Yes, I agree. This is a kind of tradeoff between the amount of knowledge you remember and the elegance of the code. I mean `${var}` instead of just `$var` is fine but `(( "${n}" * "${m}" ))` instead of `(( n * m ))` is a bit too much for me. So I'm glad to always remember, for example, that _Within an [arithmetic evaluation] expression, shell variables may also be referenced by name without using the parameter expansion syntax_, that is, also without quotes and curly braces.